# iframe scroll background issue in IE8

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, internet-explorer-8, ie8-browser-mode

I'm having problem with the standard iframe background and scrolling (IE8).

I load a standard iframe with scrollbar that contains a long list. The problem occours when I'm scrolling to to the bottom of the list and then continues to scroll with the wheel. It looks like the background continues out of the iFrame and into the main area of the screen. It's hard to explain this, but look at the picture.

The only thing that seems to work is to but display: none on the iFrame. Is there a way around this. I've tried overflow: hidden but it doesn't seems to work.

another question. what's the correct way in css to set display: none into a iframe?!

[EXAMPLE PICTURE, click here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kage.png)

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of this or give us a link to a demo url?

Comment: an iframe? When I look at your image it seems like you're loading a dialog page. Could your give us more info or some code?